# Ctools multistep returning user

Tags: users, chaos-tool-suite, forms

I am trying to implement a multistep registration form where if the user drops off the first step I then email them a link several weeks later for them to continue to step-2

http://example.com/user/register/step-2

After step two is complete the receive an email asking them to verify the account.

How do I load the users previous data if I send them directly to step2 at a later date. My ctools multistep currently looks like this after following this [guide](http://www.grasmash.com/article/building-multistep-registration-form-drupal-7-using-ctools)

```
function MYMODULE_registration_ctools_wizard($step = 'step-1') {
  // Include required ctools files.
  ctools_include('wizard');
  ctools_include('object-cache');

  $form_info = array(
    // Specify unique form id for this form.
    'id' => 'multistep_registration',
    //Specify the path for this form. It is important to include space for the $step argument to be passed.
    'path' => "user/register/%step",
    // Show breadcrumb trail.
    'show trail' => TRUE,
    'show back' => FALSE,
    'show return' => FALSE,
    // Callback to use when the 'next' button is clicked.
    'next callback' => 'MYMODULE_registration_subtask_next',
    // Callback to use when entire form is completed.
    'finish callback' => 'MYMODULE_registration_subtask_finish',
    // Callback to use when user clicks final submit button.
    'return callback' => 'MYMODULE_registration_subtask_finish',
    // Callback to use when user cancels wizard.
    'cancel callback' => 'MYMODULE_registration_subtask_cancel',
    // Specify the order that the child forms will appear in, as well as their page titles.
    'order' => array(
      'step-1' => t('Step One'),
      'step-2' => t('Step Two'),
      'step-3' => t('Step Three'),
    ),
    // Define the child forms. Be sure to use the same keys here that were user in the 'order' section of this array.
    'forms' => array(
      'step-1' => array(
        'form id' => 'user_register_form'
      ),
      'step-2' => array(
        'form id' => 'MYMODULE_registration_group_info_form',
        // Be sure to load the required include file if the form callback is not defined in the .module file.
        //'include' => drupal_get_path('module', 'MYMODULE_registration') . '/MYMODULE_registration_groups_form.inc',
      ),
      'step-3' => array(
        'form id' => 'MYMODULE_registration_invite_form',
      ),
    ),
  );

  // Make cached data available within each step's $form_state array.
  $form_state['signup_object'] = MYMODULE_registration_get_page_cache('signup');


  $output = ctools_wizard_multistep_form($form_info, $step, $form_state);

  return $output;
}

function MYMODULE_registration_get_page_cache($name) {
  ctools_include('object-cache');
  $cache = ctools_object_cache_get('MYMODULE_registration', $name);
  // If the cached object doesn't exist yet, create an empty object.
  if (!$cache) {
    $cache = new stdClass();
    $cache->locked = ctools_object_cache_test('MYMODULE_registration', $name);
  }

  return $cache;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to save your signup object in `MYMODULE_registration_subtask_next`

like:

```
<?php    
    function MYMODULE_registration_subtask_next (&$form_state) {
      MYMODULE_registration_set_page_cache('signup', $form_state['signup_object']);
    }
```

and - in `MYMODULE_registration_subtask_cancel` and `MYMODULE_registration_subtask_finish` you should clean that cache, like `MYMODULE_registration_remove_page_cache('signup');`

Comment: I have updated the question to make it clearer, your answer only covers moving between steps in the same session. I would like to email the user a link to step 2 weeks later if they dropped off at step 1, hope that makes sense.

Comment: in that case you need to save the data after step one in a custom entity - or maybe use the user entity, giving them a special role or something (which you delete after completion), and them work through these objects in a cron job ...

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the guide is not complete, it provides a way to store the data but it doesn't do anything with it.

For the values in the cache to be loaded upon each request, you should put them in $form_state['input'] just after loading them

```
  // Make cached data available within each step's $form_state array.
  $form_state['signup_object'] = MYMODULE_registration_get_page_cache('signup');
  // This will override values with cache if the user has not submitted something yet
  if (empty($form_state['input']) && $form_state['signup_object']) { 
    $form_state['input'] = $form_state['signup_object'];
  }
```

Watch out for the PHP session expiration time (it should be over 2 weeks) as ctools uses that to retrieve cached data.
You should aso add a cron that expire ctools cached data or you ctools cache will grow very big due to input by non-returning anonymous users.

Comment: I have added the get_page_cache function to my question which I think is already doing what you suggest (correct me if I am wrong). What I really wanted to do is add a token to the end of the link that I could send at any point and not rely on the session not being expired or a change of device. So when they hit step-2 url with the token the user details are fetched and the registration can continue. I think this is possible if I just delete the cache if the token exists retrieve the user and add the user object to the form somehow.

Comment: This seems pretty custom to me then, I would you do not need ctools to store your data, create your own table with *hook_schema()*, fill it with (mail, token, data, timestamp, sent) columns and add a cron that regularly send mail to timestamp older than 2 weeks.
Then either a new parameter to your wizard callback for the token, or add a new menu route that set a session parameter which you can use in your form.